# ¿Por qué no me funciona bien el contador de este pequeño programa?

Tags: c

Tengo que contar los caracteres de una frase, para eso tengo lo siguiente:

```
int cont=0;
    char c;
    printf("Introduce una frase acabada en punto");
    scanf ("%c",&c);
    while (c!='.'){
        cont=cont+1;
        scanf ("%c", &c);
    }
    printf("El numero de caracteres de la frase es: %d",cont);
```

El programa es muy cutre y tal, es solo para practicar, tiene que funcionar así:

> El usuario tiene que introducir carácter por carácter para crear una
> frase y el programa tiene que decir cuantos caracteres tiene la frase

Por ejemplo, si quiero escribir 'hola' pues escribiré primero la h luego la o etc... El problema es que mi contador no funciona bien y me da mas caracteres de los que hay y no entiendo el porque.

Ejemplo:
Si yo escribo 'h' después 'o' después 'l' después 'a' y después '.' me sale que la frase tiene 8 caracteres.

Comment: Pues cutre y todo pero hace lo que dices que debería hacer. Por favor, edita la pregunta e indica con qué frases pruebas y qué resultado da el conteo (que dices que sale mal).

Comment: @Alfabravo Míralo ahora.

Comment: ¿Escribes todo de corrido o vas dando Enter tras cada letra?

Comment: @CandidMoe Enter en cada letra.

Comment: Tu programa también cuenta los Enter. Ahi está la cuenta que te falta. Estas leyendo 'h', '\n', 'o', '\n', 'l', '\n', 'a', '\n`.

Comment: @CandidMoe Anda, pues no sabia que también se contaban los Enters, muchas gracias!

Comment: Usa `scanf("%c%*c", &c)` para leer la letra y descartar el Enter. El asterisco delante de la `c` significa "leer-y-descartar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > ¿Por qué no me funciona bien el contador de este pequeño programa?

La función `scanf` está dejando un salto de línea (generado por el `ENTER`) en el búfer del teclado.

Cuando se ejecute este código:

```c
int cont=0;
char c;
printf("Introduce una frase acabada en punto");
scanf ("%c", &c);
```

Y el usuario ingrese una `H`, el búfer quedará con:

```c
\n
```

Así que la próxima vez que intentes invocar a la función `scanf`, no pausará el programa, porque leerá el caracter que se encuentre en el búfer (que no necesariamente debe ser un salto de línea).

Así que una posible solución, es hacer que la función `scanf` ignore ese salto de línea de esta forma:

```c
while (c!='.')
{
     cont=cont+1;
     scanf(" %c", &c);
}
printf("El numero de caracteres de la frase es: %d", cont);
```

Como verás, el **espacio** que dejé en el primer parámetro de la función `scanf`, hará que ignore el salto de línea que esté en el búfer y de esta manera, el programa se pausará.

También podrías usar un `do-while` para evitar escribir dos veces la función `scanf`:

```c
int cont=0;
char c;
printf("Introduce una frase acabada en punto");
do
{
     cont=cont+1;
     scanf(" %c", &c);
}while(c != '.');
printf("El numero de caracteres de la frase es: %d", cont);
```